# IE9 negative top margin - floated and cleared child makes the element stuck

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-9, margin

I've run into a strange problem in IE9, spent a lot of time tracking and reproducing it.

So we have the following markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="movable">
        <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
        <div class="stuff special">Stuff Special</div>
        <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
        <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in something like this:

[image: The boxes before tinkering]

We would like to move the yellow box up (out of the container) and make the `.stuff` elements clearing. We would like to float **at least one** `.stuff` element, let's choose `.special`, so we do this:

```
.movable { margin-top: -70px; }
.stuff { clear: both; }
.special { float: left; }
```

**On the left, the results we get in Chrome and Firefox, on the right IE9:**

[image: Left: Chrome, Right: IE9]

As you can see, **IE9 is somehow stuck applying the negative `margin-top`**, and it will always get stuck **at the element which has right or left `float` and `clear: both;` applied on it at the same time**. The combination of these two properties is needed, only one of them will not trigger this behavior.

[A jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem and can be played with](http://jsfiddle.net/6Phx6/5/)

This problem has come up in a quite large application, for certain reasons I cannot use `top` instead of `margin-top`, positioning would break other stuff.

Anybody has any idea how to help IE9 correctly display this?

Comment: Which subversion of IE9 are you using?

Comment: Version: 9.0.8112.16421, Update Versions: 9.0.15

Comment: applying clear and float on the same element is counter intuitive. clear the floats after the float.

Comment: @albert It is not counter-intuitive at all. Clears the previous float and starts a new one. Comes handy in several situations.

Comment: my bad; i can't disagree with a solution you find useful. offhand, looked out of place to me. apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the `.movable element`. I don't know how you're normally doing it, adding a clearfix class etc. If not, just add `overflow:hidden` to it for example. Floating it also fixes it, but that might not work for your real page.

```
.movable { margin-top: -70px; overflow:hidden; }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Phx6/13/)

Comment: I haven't forgotten, the main point of the demo is that you can add/remove it yourself with the Toggle button :). The floated element itself is cleared by the following element, could you create a working demo of your proposed solution?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6Phx6/13/

Sorry, didn't notice :). I would advise clearing it in a more appropriate way, but it doesn't matter. Like I said, you can also float it.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. This is indeed a useful workaround, even though a clearfix should not be needed here. Blame IE... Please clean up your answer a bit, add the fiddle and a code example to it (for possible future visitors) and I will accept it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I don't think it's needed, but I'm going by the fact that IE is the only one messing it up. Heh. In any case, glad to help.